# Dynamically Style/Format a dynamically added column of a table to right aligned using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with a price column that I want right aligned.  I could easily do that, but all the rows are added later with:

```
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
```

So, there is no existing HTML to add an `id` to in the original file.  There is a `<table>` tag, but no `<tr>` or `<td>` tags.

Here is a jsFiddle with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E8NDU/3/)

[image]

I want the price right aligned.  How do I dynamically set the alignment of one column with Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript at all for that task. You can set the style of your price-column with CSS. Just add the following rule to the CSS:

```
#myTable tr td:nth-child(3) {
    text-align: right;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzerrenner/X8yqS/2/)

If you don't have the option to edit your CSS, you could set the CSS property on your inserted node:

```
cell3.style.textAlign = "right";
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzerrenner/X8yqS/3/)

Of course, the latter would also answer your question to set the style property with JavaScript.

This assumes that you know, that your price column will be the 3rd column.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  For some strange reason, the `text-align: right;` will work in JSFiddle, and not for my app.  I had to use `float: right;`.  But your answer saved me from having to use code.